# HERE mobile Premium SDK (android): Cannot initialize Map with error INCORRECT_APP_CREDENTIALS

Tags: android, here-api

I registered for a freemium plan in https://developer.here.com/plans and activate a project for my example package name `com.xyz.something`. I cloned the example apps from https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples and a edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`, setting:

- package name on top to `com.xyz.something`
- App Id, App Code and License
- and the Label and Intend (2x)

Described here: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/README.md

In the end I always end up with this error:

- Cannot initialize Map with error INCORRECT_APP_CREDENTIALS

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you updated **app/build.gradle** file as well.
**applicationId** should correspond to what you have in **AndroidManifest.xml** and what you entered when was registering on Developers Portal.

Comment: yep, app/build.gradle (not mentioned in the docs) i missed. ty!